# Detect if navigated to by Domain Name or IP address

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to detect whether a user navigated to my site via Domain Name or by IP Address? Google isn't being very helpful.

Comment: thanks, that put me on the right path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can eg. use client-side, in JavaScript (judging from the tags it is acceptable):

```
window.location.hostname
```

as per documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location

Or server-side, in PHP:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

as per documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 2):

You can check this :

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is: In PHP you have the server-variables, and this one you need:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

This will give you the domain you visitor came from :)

Comment: What is he asking then? He wants to know where his visitor came from ("navigated TO my site VIA Domain Name/IP"). If he wants to know about the host of his visitor, the OP should rephrase his question :)

Comment: This will give you the URL the user previously visited, not the domain (you can retrieve the domain/IP from it,  but it is not current site's IP).